# Peculiar issues with uploading a file from a form Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

In the future I plan on using this file to update a DB, but right now I am just trying to get the file to upload to my server.

The folder in question is chmod 777, so it should be able to accept this upload. What happens is when I submit the upload, I get an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error. There are no errors in laravel.log.

My HTML:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'import','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true)) }}

      {{ Form::file('csv') }}<br>
      {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
      {{ Form::reset('Reset') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

My controller:

```
class ImportController extends BaseController {
public function import()
$csv = Input::file('csv');
$destinationPath = public_path() . '/import';
$fileName = 'import' . now() . '.' . 'csv';
$csv->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

Redirect::to('/')->withMessage("Success");
}
```

My routes (for good measure):

```
Route::post('/import', 'ImportController@import');
Route::get('/import', 'ImportController@index');
```

I have used similar code to upload in the past with no issues... is there something going on here?

Edit:
I have found that the issue was my destinationPath. I needed to change it from /import. But now I am getting the following error despite having files=true in my form: 'Call to a member function move() on a non-object'.

Comment: This code doesn't have the problem. There's something wrong with `Redirect::to()`'s target.

Comment: I have found that the issue was my destinationPath. But now I am getting the following error despite having files=true in my form: 'Call to a member function move() on a non-object'

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect to /import path

```
Redirect::to('/import')->withMessage("Success");
```

Because it seems right now index (/) points to import post action.

Comment: I have found that the issue was my destinationPath. But now I am getting the following error despite having files=true in my form:

 'Call to a member function move() on a non-object' in

Comment: Maybe csv file is incorrect, have bad format etc? always check file with Input::hasFile('csv') and Input::file('csv')->isValid(). And try to var_dump $csv, seems nothing comes